# Ideal Weight in PHP

Tags: php, html

Here's the deal, i got a school work to do, my teacher wants me to make a application in PHP that calculates the ideal weight based on the height of a woman and a man. It's like this, the man will put it's height in a textbox and then the application will do the height - 58.0, and the woman it's the same but it's height - 44.7. I tried so hard to do it, but i don't know why when i click the submit button, all i've got it's a empty screen... It's my first PHP application, i'm beggining into it right now, could someone help me ?

Here's the HTML code:

```
<Doctype HTML>
<html lang = "pt-br">
<head>
    <title>Peso Ideal!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="peso.php">
        <p><label for="altura">Altura</label><br />
            <input type="TEXT" name="altura"></p>

            <input type="RADIO" name="sexo" value="Masculino">
                Masculino

            <input type="RADIO" name="sexo" value="Feminino">
                Feminino<br /> <br />

            <input type="SUBMIT" name="btn1" value="Calcular!">
</body>
</html>
```

and the PHP script:

```
<?php
$altura = $_POST['altura'];
$sexo = $_POST['sexo'];
$peso_masc = $sexo - 50.0;
$peso_fem = $sexo - 60.0;

    if(null !== (['btn1'])){
        $sexo_selecionado = ['sexo'];

        if($sexo_selecionado=='Masculino'){
            echo $peso_masc;
        }
        else if($sexo_selecionado == 'Feminino'){
            echo $peso_fem;
        }
    }
?>
```

Thanks...

Comment: If you're seeing a white page: maybe an error occurred which was suppressed. See error_reporting and display_errors on php.net. Also: how should this logic work: `$sexo - 50.0`? `$sexo` is either 'Masculino' or 'Feminino', so you're trying to calculate `Masculino - 50.0`. That's impossible. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most sophisticated, but pretty straight-forward:

```
if (isset($_POST['btn1'])){
    if ($_POST['sexo'] == 'Masculino') {
        $peso = $_POST['altura'] - 50;
    }
    else {
        $peso = $_POST['altura'] - 60;
    }
    echo $peso;
}
```

Comment: Worked out great, ashamed for asking something so simple ! Hahaha, thanks a lot dude !

Comment: Glad to help. Don't be ashamed everybody starts somewhere!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if(null !== (['btn1'])){
    $sexo_selecionado = ['sexo'];
```

to

```
if(null !== ($_POST['btn1'])){
    $sexo_selecionado = $sexo;
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

here is the error

```
if(null !== (['btn1']))
```

you're not accessing anything. change it to

```
if(null !== $_POST['btn1'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of things wrong with your php. I've added comments where you went wrong

```
<?php
$altura = $_POST['altura'];
$sexo = $_POST['sexo'];
$peso_masc = $sexo - 50.0; // you're subtracting the value from the male/female here, when you should be subtracting it from $altura
$peso_fem = $sexo - 60.0; //same here

if(null !== (['btn1'])){ //this should be $_POST['btn1'], also, you should use isset()
    $sexo_selecionado = ['sexo']; // this isn't how you do strings, it should be $sexo, but there's no reason for this variable, you can just test $sexo below

    if($sexo_selecionado=='Masculino'){
        echo $peso_masc;
    }
    elseif($sexo_selecionado == 'Feminino'){
        echo $peso_fem;
    }
}
?>
```

All together you'd get:

```
<?php
$altura = $_POST['altura'];
$sexo = $_POST['sexo'];
$peso_masc = $altura - 50.0;
$peso_fem = $altura - 60.0; 

if(isset($_POST['btn1'])){

    if($sexo=='Masculino'){
        echo $peso_masc;
    }
    elseif($sexo == 'Feminino'){
        echo $peso_fem;
    }
}
?>
```

Also, there's no reason for you to assign the $_POST variables to other variables, so you could condense the code to this:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['btn1'])){

    if($_POST['sexo']=='Masculino'){
        echo $_POST['altura'] - 50;
    }
    elseif($_POST['sexo'] == 'Feminino'){
        echo $_POST['altura'] - 60;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: If you're giving feedback on the entire implementation: `$_POST['altura']` is not guaranteed to be a float/integer either, so you should cast the supplied value (and throw an exception/error if it can't be converted).

Comment: @Bjorn True, there were a lot of things that need touched up from his code.